# Uniform distribution in a hash function

Tags: c, data-structures, hash, hashmap

I've written the following basic hash function for playing around with a hashmap data structure:

```
static int ht_hash(const char* s, int prime, int num_buckets)
{
    long hash = 0;
    size_t len_s = strlen(s);
    for (int i=0; i < len_s; i++)
    {
        // 1. left-most digit should be prime^^len-1, right-most should be prime^^0
        long prime_to_power = (long) pow(prime, len_s - (i+1));
        // 2. multiple that value for the digit times the code (asci code in this case) for that char
        hash += prime_to_power * s[i];
    }
    // 3. hash / modulo
    hash %= num_buckets;
    return (int) hash;

}
```

How can one determine a 'good' bucket size or 'prime' for a basic hashing function such as the above? I understand that the goal is to have a uniform distribution. But is there a way to do this other than, for example, to do a brute-force with 100k values, for example:

```
for (int num_buckets=0; num_buckets < 100000; num_buckets++)
    // for (int prime=1; prime < 10000; prime=get_next_prime())
    // or, if we want to grab all numbers, not just prime and see for ourselves
    for (int number=1; number < 100000; number++)

        // ... store some histogram-like data
```

Or, is this more an abstract mathematical area where there are proofs showing possible conditions/constraints for a uniform distribution? In other words, what might be a good way to learn more about hashing functions and how they are done? and how they are confirmed to be uniform?

Comment: Of possible interest: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.06804.pdf

Comment: @DavidEisenstat thanks for that link, the math is a bit beyond my current abilities/understanding (know calculus, diffeq, and LA). What area in math would that fall into: for example would a basic undergrad course in number theory be sufficient to understand the math underpinnings of that paper?

Comment: I think an intro discrete math course would get you most of the way there.